# How does python do list slices and modification on the LHS?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I know how thew syntax works for this, but I would like to know the process of how python replaces and alters the list on the left hand side.
Ex.

```
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
L[0:2] = [5]
print L #L is now [5, 2, 3, 4]
```

How does python go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 2.7, which your question is tagged with, it's the `__setslice__` magic method.  The details are documented [here in the datamodel section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setslice__).

```
__setslice__(self, i, j, sequence)
    Called to implement assignment to self[i:j].
```

This is an old interface for backwards compatibility.  If you, for example, assign to a slice with `L[0:2:]` (which should be equivalent), you actually go through the new interface of `__setitem__`.

To see what goes on under the hood, you can create your own class and inherit a list:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     def __setslice__(self, *args):
...         print '__setslice__ called with args:', args 
...         list.__setslice__(self, *args)
...     def __setitem__(self, *args):
...         print '__setitem__ called with args:', args        
...         list.__setitem__(self, *args)
...
```

Let's look at a few examples:

```
>>> L = MyList([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> L[0:2] = [5]
__setslice__ called with args: (0, 2, [5])
```

The 3 arguments passed are always the left and right endpoints, and then the object on the right hand side of the assignment.

```
>>> L[0:2:] = [5]
__setitem__ called with args: (slice(0, 2, None), [5])
```

Using the slice with a step will always go through the new interface of `__setitem__`, and pass an instance of a [slice](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) object rather than start/stop indices.

```
>>> L[1:] = [5]
__setslice__ called with args: (1, 9223372036854775807, [5])
```

Omitting the endpoint uses `sys.maxint` (omitting the start uses 0).

```
>>> L[::] = 'potato'
__setitem__ called with args: (slice(None, None, None), 'potato')
```

The object on the right doesn't have to be a list.

The last thing that I want to mention is that you only have to muck around with `__setslice__` if you are deriving from the built-in list type.  Usually you *don't* want to do that, if you are writing new code the modern way would be to inherit an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), specifically [`collections.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Sequence) is the obvious choice for list-like structures.  That way you don't have to worry about all the warts and hacks that the built-in list has for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 7):

This is accomplished with the `__setitem__` or `__setslice__` methods.  (`__setslice__` is deprecated IIRC and removed in python3.x).

For a list, the expression:

```
L[start: stop] = some_iterable
```

Will take the items from `some_iterable` and replace the elements at indices from start to stop (non-inclusive).  So, in your demo code, you have:

```
L[0:2] = [5]
```

This takes the elements at index `0` and `1` and replaces them with `5`.

Note that the replacement list doesn't need to be the same length as the the sublist that it is replacing.

Perhaps a better way to think of it is as an in-place way to do the following:

```
L[a:b] = c

# equivalent to the following operation (done in place)
L[:a] + list(c) + L[b:]
```

If you're actually curious about *how* it happens, the source code is the best reference.  [PyList_SetSlice](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l678) calls [list_ass_slice](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l569) which turns the iterable on the right hand side into a sequence (`tuple` or `list` IIRC) .  It resizes the array to hold the proper amount of data, copies the stuff on the right of the slice into the proper location and then copies in the new data.  There are a few different code paths (and orders of operations) depending on whether the list grows or shrinks, but that's the basic gist of it.

Comment: Thank you so much!